# How to take panorama of sky with Google Pixel 3?

Tags: camera, google-camera, google-pixel-3-xl

I'm trying to take a panoramic photo of the sunset, but the only option I see to do this is called "Photo Sphere".  When I select this it wants me to start at the dot, which appears to be level with the horizon.  But if I do this it will greatly detract from the panorama because everything I want to see is in the sky and there is an ugly setting underneath it.

How can I take a panorama without having to start in some arbitrary location that Google wants me to?

Update: I just noticed there is a "panorama" tab off to the left of the default camera, but it only shoots in one direction and doesn't let me add additional up/down space if there isn't enough in portrait mode.